# CSS vários backgrounds

Tags: css, background, multiple

Eu tenho este código, e não percebo porque não funciona, o que eu queria era ter dois backgrounds um no top center outro bottom center. mas só funciona em baixo e não é esse o suposto ficar em baixo. Alguma sugestão? Obrigado

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url('../imgs/aboutUsBg1.jpg') center top no-repeat, 
                  url('../imgs/aboutUsBg2.jpg') center bottom no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Podem ver a página aqui se quiserem dar uma olhada: http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/about_us.html

Comment: Acredito que não é possível fazer isso, acho melhor você ajuntar as duas imagens e fazer delas uma só...

Comment: Ok Obgado vou fazer isso

Comment: é possível, sim.. mas mesmo assim, ainda acho que é melhor juntar em uma imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo que funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/dke7L/

- Lembre-se de deixar transparente as divs que vem dentro de body.
   Tudo o que vier no corpo da página, aparecerá acima do background do body.
  Eu dei uma olhada em sua página e uma `<div id="missValBar">` tem o fundo branco, que está ficando por cima do background.
- o seu `body` tem esse CSS-inline: `background-position: 50% 1143.2px, 50%;`, ele está mexendo com o fundo da página. Remova-o.

Comment: Obgado mas como pode ver nas outras pags que teem só uma imagem de fundo mas com repeat-y resulta