# Como faço para juntar 3 backgrounds?

Tags: css

É o seguinte, eu tenho uma div com id="1". E tenho 3 imagens, com 20 pixeis cada que pretendo que sejam os meus backgrounds, mas pretendo que a minha div, tenha os 3 backgrounds, de forma um do lado esquerdo do outro. Ou seja mal termina um, o outro começa ao seu lado.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Verifique esse link, se te ajuda
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10627/css-v%C3%A1rios-backgrounds

Comment: Pretendo que seja um do lado esquerdo do outro, e sem espaçamentos.

Comment: @Gonçalo Não seria mais fácil juntar os backgrounds no Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o background para esse objetivo, conforme o exemplo a seguir

```css
body {
    background: url("https://dummyimage.com/210x200/1eff00/fff&text=imagem+1") left top,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/210x200/0062e3/fff&text=imagem+2") center top no-repeat,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/210x200/f7c600/fff&text=imagem+3") right top no-repeat;
    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;   
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Código original [daqui](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDP8TUPIXCQ2).